# while loop performnace single core vs multicore machine

Tags: java

I have faced below interview question sometime back, how the below loop will behave in single core and multicore systems, meaning does it affect single core, multicore performance or it's the same?

```
  while (r < 1000000) { //assume r = 0 initially
        t = r*r;
        r++
    }
```

Comment: I don't see threads here.. There'll be no difference.

Comment: I think since this is runs in a singe thread there won't be any difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There will be no difference. A single thread always runs in a single core. If you want to utilize more than one core, you should divide the job into parts and run them in different threads.

For more information, check some multithreaded programming examples/tutorials online.

Answer (score 2):

Since you haven't posted the full code I assume that your loop runs in the main thread . Therefore there is only a single thread that is running at a particular moment. Your loop getting execute inside that thread.

In multicore system it uses often to run parallel threads or process in different cores. Since you are having a single Thread, it will always get executed inside a single core. There won't be any time difference.

Comment: Yes, it's a loop inside main method. Thanks a lot for your reply.